# Does anybody know why the new Gnome 3.4 changing wallpaper does not change?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I've upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and installed Gnome 3.4.

I've selected the default Gnome wallpaper which is supposed to change througouht the day but it does not change...

Answer (score 1):

You may simply be encountering a bug or shortcoming in the wallpaper. As far as I know it only changes in intensity depending on the time of day.

You may not even notice the change in fact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you're wrong regarding the "intensity depending" thing. There's 3 different wallpapers and a xml file to configure the changing throughout the day, with transitions timer and so on ...